# WCF Multiple Service Configuration Issue

Tags: wcf, configuration

#### Scenario

#### Ignoring that fact that some of the settings might be wrong and inconsistent or just not there!.

Why does the program fail to compile when I try and put these 2 separate configurations for WCF Services into the same APP.CONFIG file? One was writen by myself and another by a friend, yet I cannot get the application to compile. What have I missed?

#### ERROR

Type Initialization Exception

#### CODE

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>

  <!--START Service 1 CONFIGURATION-->
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="tcpServiceEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
       transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
       hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
       maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
         maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:05:00"
         enabled="true" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  
  <client>
    <endpoint address=""
     binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpServiceEndPoint"
     contract="ListenerService.IListenerService"
     name="tcpServiceEndPoint" />
  </client>
  <!--END Service 1 CONFIGURATION-->


 <!--START Service 2 CONFIGURATION-->
  <services>
    <service name="UploadObjects.ResponseService">
      <!-- Define NetMsmqEndpoint -->
      <endpoint address=""
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="UploadObjects.IResponseService"
              bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding"/>
     </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TransactedBinding">
        <security mode="None" />
       </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--END Service 2 CONFIGURATION-->

   </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: It would be nice to get the actual error...

Comment: how are you encrypting and signing your messages. i expected to see x509 mentioned somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Your `<client>` endpoint has no address:

   ```
   <client>
       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="netTcpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="tcpServiceEndPoint"
                 contract="ListenerService.IListenerService"
                 name="tcpServiceEndPoint" />
   ```

   How do you expect your client code to know where to connect to?? You need to specify a full WCF service address in any client `<endpoint>`
2. Your `<service>` endpoint also is lacking an address - you either need to specify a full address here, or than you have to have a base address defined in your service! One of the two must be present:

   ```
   <services>
      <service name="UploadObjects.ResponseService">
         <endpoint address="net.tcp://YourServer:5455/YourServiceAddress"
                   binding="netTcpBinding"
                   contract="UploadObjects.IResponseService"
                   bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding"/>
      </service>
   ```

   or:

   ```
   <services>
      <service name="UploadObjects.ResponseService">
         <endpoint address=""
                   binding="netTcpBinding"
                   contract="UploadObjects.IResponseService"
                   bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding"/>
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="net.tcp://YourServer:5455/YourServiceAddress" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   ```

Also, from your question, it's not clear what you're trying to do when you get the error:

- are you trying to start up a service host that hosts the service? A console app, or IIS?
- are you trying to connect a client side to a running service?